# $ prefix for variables with jquery, global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this is probably obvious...but what exactly is jQuery doing when I prefix a variable name with '$'. I know this is placing the variable in the global namespace, but why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is completely false.

`$` is an ordinary object (actually a function) that happens to have a short name.

`$` itself is a global (a property of the `window` object)

Comment: Thanks. The reason I was thinking that $ prefixed variables were placed in the global namespace was because when I set a breakpoint in the Javascript console, I saw all of my $-prefixed variables listed under Global in the Scope Variables tab.

Comment: @ChristianBenincasa That is probably due to how you are declaring the variables rather than what they are named.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript `$` is a valid character to have in a variable name.  Adding a `$` to a variable does nothing special.

```
var $a;
var a$b;
var $;
```

These are just variables, and have no special meaning.

jQuery just makes `window.$` a reference to `window.jQuery` for syntatic sugar :-)

Answer (score 1):

A variable that starts with a `$` (e.g. `var $myvar;`) is just another variable, not different in any way.

**EDIT:**

If by "prefixing" you mean this:

```
$(myvar)
```

that is not "prefixing". I think it's called "wrapping". It "enhances" the variable. You could "wrap" even the `window` itself... http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1838-Wrapping-The-Window-Object-In-A-jQuery-Wrapper.htm

What it does is identical to `jQuery(myvar)`. `jQuery` is a function (a callable object if you will).

Comment: `$(myvar)` is called "calling a function" (people sometimes call it "wrapping" it as a jQuery object, though).  `$` is a function. :-P

Answer (score 0):

*Are you declaring a variable whose name is prefixed with `$`?*

If you write this:

```
$test = 500;
```

Then yes, you're polluting the global namespace with a variable named `$test`, which is no different than any other variable (the `$` has no special effect).  But in JQuery, you're most likely doing this:

```
$('test')
```

Which is just a simple function call. The function name is `$`, and the parameter is `'test'`

Answer (score 0):

do you mean when you are doing:

```
var $li = $("li");
```

that you are prefixing `li` with an `$`. it doesnt matter what you are calling your variables, if you want to use a prefix with `$` its up to you. If it helps you when you debug your code knowing that a $variableName is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't change the way the javascript language works.

there are two ways to create a global variable

```
globalVariable = ...
```

or

```
window.globalVariable = ...
```

The first not working with javascript strict mode

When jquery.js is executed it addes to global functions to the window object
$ and jQuery

It can't change wether your variables are local or global that's up to you.